# SpriteKit, create a navigation menu to sit on top of all scenes

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite-kit

Still getting used to sprite kit and I have no prior experience with any kind of game engine on iOS.

What I'd like to do is have a menu sit at the top of each scene that allows users to navigate back and forth. (It's for a book styled game and will have left and right arrows).

Now this is simple enough to do by just adding some buttons at the top of the scene, but I would like to be able to create a subclass that contains all of this functionality and just add it to the scenes that require it. This way edits will only have to be made once.

How would I go about creating something like this? 
The menu will need to be able to present next/prev scenes in the correct order.

I feel as though this should be a really simple thing to do, but I haven't been able to find much information on it.

EDIT: So far I can think of 3 ways to go about this.

1. Write the navigation code for each scene individually.
2. Subclass an SKNode containing the navigation buttons and use that in each scene.
3. Create an SKScene with the required functionality and use subclasses of that for each scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create a NavigationMenu class that subclasses SKNode ? Then add whatever you want to it. You could create multiple instances or one that you share with any scene that needs it.

Comment: Is there a way to present a previous scene in the same state it was left in?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean. If you haven an instance of a NavigationMenu class, you can add/remove it from the display list. So unless you do something to change it's state, it doesn't change. right ? Or are you asking a new question ?

Comment: It was a new separate question. 
I ended up just subclassing SKScene, wrote the navigation code in there, and used that to create all the other scenes.